# evosuite: ERROR MeasureCoverage - Not possible to access to clients

Tags: code-coverage, evosuite

I am currently trying to use EvoSuite to measure code coverage of existing test code. Everything works fine at first. But it seems not work anymore.  I always got the error message:

```
* Starting client
[MASTER] 21:36:10.605 [main] ERROR MeasureCoverage - Not possible to access to clients
```

Is there something I did not notice to use this mode? Thank you for answering my questions.